# Can the standard multigrid performance be used for time-dependent PDEs?

Tags: pde, finite-difference, iterative-method, discretization, multigrid

Consider a time dependent pde(i.e u(x,t)).I know when only space-coarsening is used the standard multigrid performance can be applied but what if instead we use only time-coarsening?Can we apply the standard multigrid for solving the spatial problem in order to take one time step(i.e going from t1 to t2)?

Comment: Yes. That is, for example, the algorithm used in the XBraids library.

Comment: So to be crystal clear.By applying a time-coarsening techique we can use multigrid to coarse space dimension in order to take a time step right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Search for "multigrid in time".

Comment: I did.One last question since you seem to have a solid knowledge on this topic and I am a little bit confused.The FCF-relaxation on temporal mesh(solving a block jacobi) leading to an another linear system(spatial system Φ*u_i=u_i-1 in you use an implicit scheme) .So I want to know if you have to solve this system "exactly" using for example a multigrid method in space in order to i-1 to i or just to use few iteration of GS for example and go on with FCF relaxation.In some examples they find the "exact" solution in every time step for all grid and i got confused.Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't actually know. What I stated above is roughly the extent of my knowledge :-)